# Mongoose 'Killed'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Trying to run a test comparing MySQL I/O to Mongo. I'm suing Node with Mongoose, and entering a bunch of records in a loop. If I try to do too many records with Mongo, it quits. The only error I get is 'Killed'.

Any ideas from anyone, or have they seen this? Running in Amazon AWS on Ubuntu, node running on a small, and Mongo running on another small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the [linux out of memory killer](https://web.archive.org/web/20160513060937/http://seriousbirder.com/blogs/linux-out-of-memory-oom-killer/) killing your process when the available memory is exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a resource issue, but you can probably get around it by using the async.eachLimit function, to run your loop in "batches".

https://github.com/caolan/async#each